# ActiveMQ Artemis. Reliable cluster with synchronous replication

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to configure a cluster with the following expected behavior:

1. Сluster must be HA ( 3 nodes at least).
2. I have queues in which it is important to maintain processing order. The consumer always reads this queue in a single thread. If he took the message, then we consider our task completed.
3. I don't need load balancing - it is important for me to maintain the order of messages.
4. I want to avoid split-brain.
5. If we have 3 nodes, then if 1 of the nodes fails, the cluster should continue to work.

I tried following configurations:

1. master + slave + slave with replication.

It works. But does not solve the problem of split brain

2. master + slave + slave  + Pinger

As far as I understand, this does not give a 100% guarantee of detecting network problems. We can also get split-brain.

3. 3 pairs of live/backup nodes.

This is solved split brain problem but how can we avoid the following situation:

1. Producer send message to group A in queue (where important to maintain processing order)
2. Group A crashed ( 1/3 of all nodes 2/6)
3. The message stored in the journal of group A
4. Cluster continue to work;
5. Producer send message to group B in queue (where important to maintain processing order)
6. Consumer got this message first; We did not support the required message order.

How should I build a cluster to solve these problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve the behavior you want using replication. You need to use a [shared store](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#shared-store) between the nodes. If you *must* use 3 nodes then I would recommend master + slave + slave. Otherwise I'd recommend master + slave.

Also, for what it's worth, replication is not synchronous *within the broker*. It is asynchronous and non-blocking. However, it is still reliable. For example, when a broker is configured for HA with replication and it receives a durable message from a client it will persist that message to disk *and* send it to the replicated backup concurrently without blocking. However, it will wait for *both* operations to finish before responding to the client that it has received the message. This allows much greater message throughput than using a synchronous architecture internally although the whole process will *appear* to be synchronous to external clients.

Also, it's worth noting that work is underway to change how replication works to make it more robust against split brain and to enable a single master + slave pair that is suitable for production use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is what I need! Please advise the article / documentation / success story on how to build a distributed shared store. Sorry, i can't find information in google.I will create a new question where I will describe the detailed requirements

Comment: You need a SAN or a NAS (e.g. NFS) for your shared store. Broker configuration details are in [the ActiveMQ Artemis HA documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#shared-store).

Comment: @JustinBertram, I was looking at latest performance tests at https://softwaremill.com/mqperf/ and don't understand why active-active is not used and why replication is synchronous. Docs state: "colocated (both live and backup)" and as you mention replication is async. And I was under the impression that "However, it will wait for both operations to finish" was not true. As when I kill one active node the backup didn't had all the messages there (which is fine) and when the "active" node comes up again the messages are persisted there.

Comment: @la00, you really should ask a new question instead of commenting on this one (although I will update my answer to clarify synch vs. asynch for replication).

Comment: @JustinBertram sorry. Thanks for the update, from the docs I thought the feature was already in place. The comparison with Kafka don't seem fair as it's probably only guarantee that one node got the message, which for most cases it's OK (+ performance). Meanwhile, I'll try to do one for my use case, i.e. 3 nodes, colocated with client side HA.

Comment: You thought *what* feature "was already in place"?

Comment: I agree that a performance comparison between ActiveMQ Artemis and Apache Kafka is not really "apples-to-apples" as they say. Kafka is not a traditional message broker and therefore doesn't provide many of the guarantees and features of one. It's more of a "streaming" solution.

Comment: FWIW, the colocation feature & configuration elements will be deprecated in the foreseeable future. See more info [here](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/DISCUSS-Deprecate-colocated-configuration-in-Artemis-td4754946.html).